# Exchange not getting created automatically when using multiple rabbitTemplate using spring for RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, spring-rabbit

I was using CachingConnectionFactory and making it a bean so that the queues and the exchanges will be created automatically if they don't exist. I created another bean RabbitTemplate and inside it I set an exchange.

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate receiptRabbitTemplate() throws URISyntaxException {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory(rabbitMQServiceScheme,
            rabbitMQServiceHostName, rabbitMQServiceContextRoot, rabbitMQServiceUser, rabbitMQServicePassword));
    template.setMandatory(true);
    template.setChannelTransacted(true);
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    objectMapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    converter.setJsonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    template.setMessageConverter(converter);
    template.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
    template.setExchange("test.exchange"); //--------------------<
    return template;
}
```

Now I'm adding another RabbitTemplate so that I can send message to another exchange. Since it's in the same virtual machine, I'm using the same ConnectionFactory bean.

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate receiptRabbitTemplate() throws URISyntaxException {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory(rabbitMQServiceScheme,
            rabbitMQServiceHostName, rabbitMQServiceContextRoot, rabbitMQServiceUser, rabbitMQServicePassword));
    template.setMandatory(true);
    template.setChannelTransacted(true);
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    objectMapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    converter.setJsonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    template.setMessageConverter(converter);
    template.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
    template.setExchange("anothertest.exchange");//---------------<
    return template;
}
```

But when I try to send message, only one of the exchange is being created. And for the other I get error

```
Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In order for **any** exchange to be declared, you need a `RabbitAdmin` bean and each exchange must be defined as a bean (not just set in the template).

See [Configuring the broker](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration).